# PHP PDO variable insertion incompatible with SQLite

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sqlite

when I run the following:

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:/path/to/database.db');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS :user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, time INTEGER NOT NULL, ping TEXT NOT NULL);');
$user = "me";
$stmt->execute(array('user' => $user));
```

I get the following error, referencing the `:user` part of the SQL:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ":user": syntax error in /datasql.php:21\nStack trace:\n#0 /datasql.php(21): PDO->prepare('CREATE TABLE IF...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /datasql.php on line 21

I can't find anything wrong with the SQL and if I run the command without the variable insertion, it runs fine.

What is causing this error?
Thanks ahead!

Comment: you can't bind a table (or column).

Comment: Thanks, you're right... That was impossible to find with google...

Comment: You're welcome.